# Cross product of operators in exponential: numerical solution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

**Short version**:

Numerical solution to a quantum system.

I have my discretised wavefunction is real space $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ and in momentum space $\tilde\psi(\mathbf{k}) = \mathcal{F} \left [ \psi(\mathbf{r}) \right ]$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a (appropriately scaled) Fourier transform.

I have to numerically work out the application of this operator:
$$ \exp \left ( \hat{\mathbf{r}}\times \hat{\mathbf{k}}  \right ) \psi(\mathbf{r}). $$

If it were not in the exponential, then I could just do the following:
$$(\hat{\mathbf{r}}\times \hat{\mathbf{k})}\, \psi(\mathbf{r}) \rightarrow \hat{\mathbf{r}} \times \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left \{ \hat{\mathbf{k}} \left ( \mathcal{F} \left [ \psi(\mathbf{r}) \right ] \right ) \right \},$$
because $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$ is diagonal for $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ and $\hat{\mathbf{k}}$ is diagonal for $\tilde\psi(\mathbf{k})$.

But how can I work how the *exponential* of this operator?

**Background**

The [Gross-Pitaveskii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation) equation is, for $m = \hbar = 1$:
$$ i \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} = \left ( \underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2}_{\hat H_{\mathrm{kin}}} + \underbrace{V(\mathbf{x},t)}_{\hat H_{\mathrm{pot}}} + \underbrace{g|\psi|^2}_{\hat H_{\mathrm{int}}} \right )\psi ,$$
and a typical numerical solution to it is the split-step (Fourier) method which consists in splitting the time evolution step between position and momentum space.

The formal solution is:

$$\psi(\mathbf{r}, t+\delta t)  = \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} (\hat H_{\mathrm{int}} +\hat H_{\mathrm{pot}})\right ) \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} \hat H_{\mathrm{kin}}\right )\psi(\mathbf{r},t) + \mathcal{O}(\delta t^2)$$

Since $\hat H_{\mathrm{kin}}$ is diagonal in momentum space, and $\hat H_{\mathrm{int}} +\hat H_{\mathrm{pot}}$ is diagonal in position space, we have:
$$  \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} \hat H_{\mathrm{kin}}\right ) \tilde\psi(\mathbf{k}) = \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} k^2\right ) \tilde\psi(\mathbf{k}), \\
 \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} (\hat H_{\mathrm{int}} +\hat H_{\mathrm{pot}})\right )\psi(\mathbf{r}) =  \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} (V(\mathbf{r}) + g|\psi|^2)\right )\psi(\mathbf{r}) ,$$
that is the operator operation just resulted in a phase factor multiplication.

Since the momentmum psace wavefunction $\tilde \psi(\mathbf{k})$ and the real space one $\psi(\mathbf{r})$ are related by a Fourier Transfor;:
$$ \tilde \psi(\mathbf{k}) = \mathcal{F} \left [ \psi(\mathbf{r}) \right ], $$

the solution step is:

$$ \psi(\mathbf{r}, t+\delta t) =  \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} (V(\mathbf{r}) + g|\psi|^2)\right ) \cdot \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left \{  \exp\left (-\frac{i \delta t}{\hbar} k^2\right ) \mathcal{F} \left [ \psi(\mathbf{r}) \right ] \right \} .$$

So that all $\mathbf{r}$ dependent functions act on the real space wavefunction $\psi(\mathbf{r})$, and the $\mathbf{k}$ dependent function (kinetic energy) acts on the momemntum space one $\hat \psi(\mathbf{k})$.

Now, I want to add a term to the Hamiltonian $-\Omega \mathbf{L}_z \ -\Omega \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p} = -\Omega \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{k} $, to account for rotations (angular momentum).

This would require a phase factor like:

$$ \propto \exp \left ( \mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{k}  \right ), $$

which involves both $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ and hence cannot be easily "separated" .

And this brings us back to the initial part of the question.

**What does $\psi$ look like**

I would use imaginary time evolution to find the ground state of the particular system (with a certain potential, interaction, and angular momentum). So my initial $\psi$ is going to be a either a uniform array or a gaussian or sth.